# Bootloop Problem of My Own Brand New Board w/ ESP32-S3 Chip

Tags: bootloader, esptool

We made our own board with ESP32-S3 (FN8 Model with 8 MB Flash internal). We see bootloop when we first turn it on. After looading bootloader.bin (and many different *.bin files) we still see bootloop problem and we get the following messages from COM port. We use Windows CMD for esptool.exe to load *.bin files.

ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x7 (TG0WDT_SYS_RST),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40043ac8
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fcd0108,len:0x1634
load:0x403b6000,len:0xe74
load:0x403ba000,len:0x31c8
Checksum failure. Calculated 0x8e stored 0xde
ets_main.c 329
... (loops) ...

How can we solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

We have tested many *.bin files (bootloader.bin, firmware.bin, combined.bin, helloworld-esp32s3.bin, bootloader_esp32s3.bin, etc) to get rid of bootloop. But no solution.

[Text from COM port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soBAs.png)